# Vs code showing error in c/c++ programs cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdiagnostics-color=always"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I can build and run programs on eclipse but when I switch to VS Code its showing erros. I have followed the documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp but its not working

> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

```
Starting build...
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64-bin_x86_64-mingw_20111101_sezero\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe" -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\amala\OneDrive\Desktop\c\k.c -o C:\Users\amala\OneDrive\Desktop\c\k.exe
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdiagnostics-color=always"

Build finished with error(s).
```

Comment: 20111101?  That sounds like an ancient build, and it probably doesn't support color diagnostics.

Comment: It says *unrecognized command line option* `"-fdiagnostics-color=always"`. That seems like an easy cure. Get rid of the `-fdiagnostics-color=always` option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have something like this in your `.vscode/tasks.json`
configuration file:

```json
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "args": [
      "-fdiagnostics-color=always", // remove this from your configuration
      "-g", "${file}",
      "-o",
      "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```